# How to check for checkboxes in a specific html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was working on a html document that has 3 elements with the following ids:
1.Inbox
2.Compose
3.Sent
Only one one element is displayed at a time(l'm using css display:none attribute to hide the other 2)and they are toggled using html buttons and jquery.
All the elements have checkboxes but i need to select only the checkboxes of the visible element.
How do I go about this?

I have the following code but it selects all checkboxes in the html document

```
$('.checkbox-toggle').click(function
 (){
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks')
    if (clicks) {
        //Uncheck all checkboxes
    } else {
       //Check all checkboxes
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wait, you're asking about a specific case where the JS does not work with a specific HTML and CSS... — without showing the HTML and CSS? Why? How are we supposed to know what `$(this).data('clicks')` is? Have you searched about how to **filter only visible elements**? Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite easy issue to solve, if I have understood correctly. To set the checked state of a checkbox you can do this:

```js
$('.checkbox-toggle').click(function
 (){
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks')
    if (clicks) {
        //Uncheck all checkboxes
        document.getElementById("Inbox").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("Compose").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("Sent").checked = false;
    } else {
       //Check all checkboxes
       document.getElementById("Inbox").checked = true;
       document.getElementById("Compose").checked = true;
       document.getElementById("Sent").checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Also, are you working on the CS50 web project? Anyway, I hope this helped, and if you can next time, add all of the HMTL. Good Luck :)